# Why is my PHP not autostarting with NginX on Windows 10?

Tags: php, windows, nginx

I'm running a new install of **Windows 10**. I need to create a local testing environment for PHP. I've set up and run NginX/PHP servers on Ubuntu Linux before, but never on Windows. I've installed the NginX and PHP binaries for Windows.

After I've booted up and logged in, if I cd to `C:\nginx` and run `nginx.exe`, the Nginx server starts up and runs fine, and I get the "Welcome to NginX" screen at `http://127.0.0.1`.

Then, if I cd to `C:\nginx\php` and run `php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c c:/nginx/php/php.ini`, the PHP server runs, and I can access `http://127.0.0.1/php.info` and get the output of `php_info();`. So it seems everything is installed okay.

My goal now, is to to have the PHP server autostart when I boot the machine. I downloaded the [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/), and opened a command prompt in Administraror mode, and ran `nssm edit nginx`. I filled out the screens as follows:

[image: nssm nginx application]

[image: nssm nginx details]

Then I did the same for PHP:

[image: nssm php application]

[image: nssm php details]

However, while NginX seems to be starting at boot, PHP does not. After a boot, without manually starting anything at the command line, I get the NginX welcome screen. However, if I try to view the PHP info page, I get the following message:

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1.

**How do I get PHP to autostart on boot?**

This is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include             mime.types;
    default_type        text/html;
    sendfile            on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;

    server {

        #Uncomment and edit the line below if you want to use a custom domainname
        #server_name    your.domain.com;

        listen          80;
        root            c:/nginx/html;

    location ~ .php$ {
        root html;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME c:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `nginx.conf` seems OK.

> ... However, while NginX seems to be starting at boot ...

I wouldn't trust NGINX welcome page, it most likely comes from cache. I also don't trust a service status `Running` unless there are nginx processes started by nssm.

In my tests both nginx and php services were not started properly.

I needed to set `AppNoConsole=1` for both services to make them work.

[According to the author(s)](https://nssm.cc/download) this is a known issue with Windows 10 Creators Update.

> 2017-04-26: Users of Windows 10 Creators Update should use prelease
>   build 2.2.4-101 to avoid an issue with services failing to start. If
>   for some reason you cannot use that build you can also set
>   AppNoConsole=1 in the registry, noting that applications which expect
>   a console window may behave unexpectedly.

You can change this setting via `NSSM Service Editor GUI > Process > Console window`. Just clear the checkbox and click Edit service. It's done.

The same operation can be done with commands too.

```
net stop php
net stop nginx

nssm set php AppNoConsole 1
nssm set nginx AppNoConsole 1

net start nginx
net start php
```